# What naming conventions exist for the primary Node.js file?

Tags: node.js, filenames

*This question has been completely edited in hopes that it will be reopened.*

The naming of the main Node.js file is something left to the user and and does not seem to be defined by any well established convention. In hopes of finding a good name, I am curious if there are naming conventions in other parts of the Node.js ecosystem that might suggest a name to use.

Some names I have seen are: `app.js`, `index.js`, `main.js`, `server.js`, etc.

Please provide only well documented standards in answers.

Comment: Let's just call everything `a.out`.

Comment: I rewrote this question to remove the opinion-based element. Please consider reopening it with the new text. Thank you.

Comment: The late computer scientist Phil Karlton once famously said: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NPM seems to suggest a standard whereby one can define the primary file in the `package.json` file like so:

```
"scripts": {"start": "node server.js"}
```

If no such property is set, NPM looks for a `server.js` file in the root of the package. If `server.js` exists, it will be run with Node.

This default seems to be a strong suggestion that the name `server.js` should be the standard.

Answer (score 2):

`index.js` has a special usage in Node.js. From the [Module docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

> ...
>
> If there is no package.json file present in the directory, then node
>   will attempt to load an index.js or index.node file out of that
>   directory. For example, if there was no package.json file in the above
>   example, then require('./some-library') would attempt to load:
>
> ./some-library/index.js
>
> ./some-library/index.node

I prefer to use `app.js` or even `main.js`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the useful answer. Do you know of any reason or do you have any opinions as to why the `index.js` rule should not be extended as a custom to the main file of Node.js apps?

Answer (score 1):

The two predominant filenames are 'app.js' & 'server.js'. Its better to go with 'server.js'. This is for nodejs *applications*. In the case of libraries, most libraries use 'index.js' and specify it in their 'main' param in the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen, app.js is the most universally accepted.

I personally prefer server.js, but this is probably biased in that I run a massive Single Page Application so all my files are .... javascript ..... and I have an app.js controller for my front-end. So it helps me distinguish the two.

#### do you know how well-established conventions start? you make a decision that is logical, and forthrightly forward it with resolute certainty - then others will follow. there clearly is no well established convention, so pick one and tell it to others.

Comment: I agree that `app.js` seems to be the most common from my experience.