# How can I identify different services when they're all named 'server.js'?

Tags: node.js, naming-conventions

Following [a common convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850028/what-naming-conventions-exist-for-the-primary-node-js-file), I generally name the main file in a project `server.js`. However, this leads to situations like this:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
21049 root      20   0 2347568 1.133g      0 D  0.0 14.5   0:32.70 node ./server.js
28201 root      20   0 1261740  69332      8 S  0.0  0.8   4:04.46 node src/server.js
26652 root      20   0  776664   9324      8 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.09 node server.js
```

One of these services has a serious memory problem--but how do I figure out what it is?

Some possible solutions that come to mind:

- Name each one differently, like `server-label-gen.js`, `server-order-mgt.js` and so on. Problem: in addition to not exactly following the naming convention, I'd eventually like to standardize things like Dockerfiles but if the files are all named differently I would need templates instead of being able to just copy.
- Pass a dummy argument to the when starting the program, so it shows up as `node ./server.js --name=label-gen`. This has the same problem with templates, plus confusion over what this argument does (if I pass `--name=order-mgt` instead does it suddenly turn into an order server?)
- Change `process.title` to something more useful. This is a common approach (postgres does this, for example) but it seems tricky to get right.

Are there best practices for this sort of thing? It seems like it would be a common problem with microservices, but I can't find anything about how other people have solved it.

Comment: If you're planning using Docker, you know each container can have it's own name.

Comment: would that apply ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18258837/102133

Comment: @calbertts Yes, but the container's name doesn't show up in process management tools. Since a few Docker releases ago, even the parent process is no longer helpful: it used to have the name of the container but now it's just 'containerd-shim <hash>'

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `process.title = process.env.PROCESS_TITLE`, or use something like [process-title](https://github.com/focusaurus/process-title) which relies on the name in the `package.json`.

I think this is the most straightforward approach one can think of.
With Docker I wouldn't bother looking at single processes within the host (`ps`) but instead use the abstraction docker provides you (`docker ps`) if you really need to.

(in general microservices push things one level up so that you don't have to worry too much about the low-level drama, where orchestrators like k8s or openshift take care of process monitoring and so on)

Comment: This is probably what I'm going to do. Regarding docker: `docker ps` only lists the containers, it doesn't show resource usage. I do use `docker stats` but I still sometimes need to identify what the parent server of a process is (e.g. I have `pdftk` running--what started it?)

Comment: BTW what I mean is that there are abstractions to use in the container world. docker ps, stats, monitoring with kubernetes, heapster etc etc...you'll be forced to move higher up at some point.